# GCD termination properties

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Given this implementation of GCD

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(reif)).

gcd(A, B, C) :-
  C #> 0, A #>= C, B #>= C,
  R #= A mod B,
  A mod C #= 0,
  B mod C #= 0,
  if_(R = 0, C = B, gcd(B, R, C)).
```

Why does it terminate when I run

```
A in 2..10, gcd(A, 14, 7), indomain(A).
```

and doesn't terminate on

```
A in 2..10, gcd(A, 16, 4), indomain(A).
```

Comment: In Scryer, with the more up-to-date `library(clpz)` instead, also your second query terminates.

Comment: The base problem is that `A in 2..10, gcd(A, 16, 4), false.` does not terminate in SWI.

Comment: Worse, in SWI 7.6.4, `A in 2..16, gcd(A, 16, 4).` fails.

Comment: ... whereas `A = 4, A in 2..16, gcd(A, 16, 4).` succeeds. That is a bug. Can you reproduce it in your version?

Comment: The last one fails in 8.2.4 on mac

Comment: Unfortunately, clpfd-development for SWI [stopped](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/108#issuecomment-301327407). Quite possible that this is a related issue.